# Rotating an image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, trigonometry

I'm trying to write a Python function to crop, rotate and resize faces. It is for a facial recognition application.
I pass the coordinates of the eyes to the function and the function processes the image (rotate it so the plane of the eyes is parallel to the horizontal axis of the image and scale/crop/resize it).
The problem is that the faces are not rotating at all. They are only being cropped.
The following function is modified to return both the rotated image and a copy of the image done before the rotation. They are identical.

```
def CropFace(image, eye_left=(0,0), eye_right=(0,0), offset_pct=(0.25,0.25), dest_sz = (250,250)):

    offset_h = math.floor(float(offset_pct[0])*dest_sz[0])
    offset_v = math.floor(float(offset_pct[1])*dest_sz[1])

    eye_direction = (eye_right[0] - eye_left[0], eye_right[1] - eye_left[1])

    rotation = -math.atan2(float(eye_direction[1]), float(eye_direction[0]))

    dist = Distance(eye_left, eye_right)

    reference = dest_sz[0] - 2.0*offset_h

    scale = float(dist) / float(reference)

    sz = image.shape
    if len(sz) > 2: sz = sz[:2]

    print rotation

    image2 = image.copy()

    mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(eye_left, rotation, 1.0)
    result = cv2.warpAffine(image, mat, sz, flags = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    crop_xy = (eye_left[0] - scale*offset_h, eye_left[1] - scale*offset_v)
    crop_size = (dest_sz[0]*scale, dest_sz[1]*scale)
    result = result[int(crop_xy[1]):int(crop_xy[1]+crop_size[1]), int(crop_xy[0]):int(crop_xy[0]+crop_size[0])]
    image2 = image2[int(crop_xy[1]):int(crop_xy[1]+crop_size[1]), int(crop_xy[0]):int(crop_xy[0]+crop_size[0])]

    return (result, image2)
```

Comment: i think the problem is for `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D` function and whit more chance the `angle` have a problem ! Checkout its argument !

Comment: @Kasra What problem are you thinking about?

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti Kasra is probably referring to the difference between the output of [math.atan2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2) and the argument to [cv2.getRotationMatrix2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrotationmatrix2d).

Comment: @beaker Right, the argument to getRotationMatrix2D is in degrees! Do one of you want to write an answer or should I do that?

Comment: @Kasra should have first crack at an answer. I only clarified because I didn't think they'd still be on 8 hours after making the initial comment.

Comment: @beaker thanks for comment that cause me see other comments

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti you have a complicated code and i just gave a proposition ! based on my experience ! so you can test test your arguments before pass them to function , e.g. by print them or ...

Comment: your rotation function format must be like this : `M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),90,1)` see http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#rotation

Comment: @Kasra I'm actually printing the argument in my code as you can see. And no, it must not be like that. I don't want to rotate my image by 90 degrees, I want to rotate it by an amount which will make the eyes parallel to the horizontal axis of the image. My code does trigonometry calculations to get the right angle. Anyway, beaker was right, the problem was in the unit difference between the two functions. Do you want to answer this or should I do that?

Comment: i just say ,you need to be sure of your argument before , why you are using `:` between your last lists `result` and `image2` ? did you had any syntax error ????

Comment: @Kasra it's working now, we already solved it. No syntax error. Those are numpy matrices.

Comment: @beaker do you want to answer?

Comment: @ its good , im glad ! so what was the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that for

```
cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale)
```

the `angle` argument is in degrees ([opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrotationmatrix2d))

while Python,

```
angle = math.atan2(y, x)
```

returns the angle in radians. ([Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2))

So the angle specified by `rotation` was in radians when OpenCV was expecting degrees.